# Solve Non Linear Equation in Python

Tags: python, nonlinear-optimization, scipy-optimize

I have Matrix A of 11*11 and vector b of length 11. I tried finding values of 11 unknowns using a linear system of equations that is

```
z= np.linalg.lstsq(A,b)
```

Which returns me a value of 11 unknown factors, so I get a vector with 11 values. Now if I add all those values it gives me the value RHS of equality.
so for example

```
3x+4y = 19
2x+2y = 23
```

I can get the value of x and y which satisfy the above equation

But I want a formulation where the product of values on LHS should give the value of RHS of equality.

```
3x*4y = 19
2x*2y = 23
```

So I need something in python that can return me value for x and y when they are a multiplicative system instead of an additive system.

Is it achievable in python?

Comment: I am not quite sure if this is an issue for your use case, but from a purely mathematical point of view, the multiplicative equations do not have unique solutions for `x` and `y` in the same manner as the two additive ones. They can be reformulated to `x*y = 19/12` and `x*y = 23/4`, respectively. So they will either be contradictory or yield `x = c/y` for some constant `c`.

Comment: @Hans Actually, I have Matrix A of 11*11 and vector b of length 11. I tried finding values of 11 unknowns using z = (A^-1)(b). Which returns me value of 11 unknown factors, so I get a vector with 11 values. Now if I add all those values it gives me the value RHS of equality. But I want a formulation where product of values on LHS should give the value of RHS of equality. I don't know how to formulate it as a product of factors

Answer (score 1):

You can write the left hand side of your system as `np.prod(A*z, axis=1)`, where `A = np.array([[3, 4],[2, 2]])` and `z = [x, y]`. However, there's no solution to your example system. The only case I see where it has a solution is when all the values in the array `np.prod(A, axis=1) / rhs` are the same.

In this case, you can solve it numerically by means of [`scipy.optimize.root`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.root.html):

```py
from scipy.optimize import root

# note that np.prod(A, axis=1) / rhs = [1, 1]
A = np.array([[3, 4],[2, 2]])
rhs = np.array([12, 4])

def Eq(z):
    return np.prod(A*z, axis=1) - rhs

result = root(Eq, x0=np.ones(2))
```

where `result.x` contains the solution. Note that the solution is not guaranteed to be unique and will depend on the starting point `x0`.